# Python, update cached property when field of attribute changes

Tags: python, caching, functools

I'll try to take a dummy example to explain my goal: updating a cache (defined with @cached_property) computed from an instance attribute.

Let's say I have an object AllCircles that is composed of a tuple of Circles. Each Circle is defined with its radius. I want to cache the value of the biggest radius as a property of AllCircles. Here's what I did:

```py
from functools import cached_property

class Circle(): 
    def __init__(self, radius: float): 
        self.radius = radius
        
class AllCircles(): 
    def __init__(self, circles: (Circle)):
        self._circles = tuple(circles)
        
    @property 
    def circles(self): 
        print("Call getter")
        return self._circles
    
    @circles.setter
    def circles(self, value):
        print("Call setter")
        self.__dict__.pop('max_radius', None)
        self._circles = value
    
    @cached_property
    def max_radius(self): 
        print("Compute cached property radius")
        return max([_.radius for _ in self.circles])
```

I can define an object AllCircles from a set of Circles, and call max_radius to get the biggest value.

```py
> my_circles = AllCircles([Circle(4), Circle(3)])
> my_circles.max_radius
    Compute cached property radius
    Call getter
    4
```

Which is ok. If I call the function again, I get:

```py
> my_circles.max_radius
    4
```

as nothing's printed, I guess the cache is called, that's ok.
If I set the circles:

```py
> my_circles.circles = [Circle(5), Circle(0)]
> my_circles.max_radius
    Call setter
    Compute cached property radius
    Call getter
    5
```

I again get the right value, because setting a new object `circles` calls the setter, and its `self.__dict__.pop()`method empties the cache.

However, if I directly modify the radius of a circle, I don't empty my cache:

```py
> my_circles.circles[0].radius = 9
> my_circles.max_radius
    Call getter
    5 # instead of 9
```

How can I change my code to update my cache when an attribute is modified directly ?

Answer (score 0):

In a way, what you're asking for seems a bit unnatural to me. Indeed, when you set `my_circles.circles[0].radius = 9`, you don't modify anything about your instance `my_circles`, so there is no natural way for it to know it should behave differently. Furthermore, the poor little `Circles` have no idea that they're part of something bigger, so they couldn't tell `my_circles`.

I guess one way you could solve your problem would be to make the radius part of the information contained in `my_circles` (or more generally, directly inform the `Circles` that they're not alone anymore by connecting them to `my_circles`).

Another way would be to force some checks from `my_circles` upon every `max_radius` request. Here it would be silly because it'd be equivalent to recomputing the max, but on more complex operations, it might just to check some hash for example.

I don't know if that helps, maybe there are other and better ways to think about this.